# .push is not a function, using Javascript and localstorage

Tags: javascript

I checked out all the links relating to this topic that I could and I found out that the reason why this is probably occurring is because my variable is not an array. I'm not too sure how to fix this. This is my code:

```
        function addStudent() {
            var newStudentInfo = {
                'studentNumber': document.getElementById("addStudentStudentNumber").value,
                'name': document.getElementById("addStudentName").value
            }

            var oldStudentInfo = [];
            oldStudentInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students")) || [];
            oldStudentInfo.push(newStudentInfo); 
            localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(oldStudentInfo));
        }
```

When looking at errors in google chrome, it tells me

```
Paused on exception: 'TypeError: oldStudentInfo.push is not a function'.
```

Where did I mess up? All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: looks like this is returning a truthy value: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"))` and it is not an array, send a `console.log()` before use it so you can see what is it

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I'm getting `Object {studentNumber: "r2424", name: "4242"}`

Comment: Originally `oldStudentInfo` is an Array with method `push`, but then you overwrite it with an object, which has not `push`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clearly that's not an array you cannot invoke the `push()` method over an `Object` like that 'cause it does not have such a method. consider to push that object inside the original `oldStudentInfo` array like this:

```
function addStudent() {
  var newStudentInfo = {
      'studentNumber': document.getElementById("addStudentStudentNumber").value,
      'name': document.getElementById("addStudentName").value
  }

  var oldStudentInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));
  // now let's check if the stored value is an array
  if(!(oldStudentInfo instanceof Array))
    oldStudentInfo = [oldStudentInfo]; // if not, create one
  oldStudentInfo.push(newStudentInfo); // push a new student inside of it
  localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(oldStudentInfo));
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the swift reply and the great clarification!